# Cannot Unpack Error from function definition

Tags: python, function, boolean

I have created a function, 'grid', to represent a 1D or 2D mesh of coordinates. When I run my code, I get the following error: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object.

I have used Boolean logic to set up my function, so that I can set an argument as == False if I want to keep it as 1D and use X values.

```
def grid(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, dx):

    if x_min and x_max and not y_min and not y_max:
        grid_x = np.arange(x_min, x_max, dx)
        return grid_x, dx

    if x_min and x_max and y_min and y_max:
        grid_x = np.arange(x_min, x_max, dx)
        grid_y = np.arange(y_min, y_max, dx)
        return grid_x, grid_y, dx



grid_x, grid_y, dx = grid(0, 10, 0, 10, 1)
```

I know that the issue is on my last line of code, but can't figure out what the error actually means with respect to my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since x_min is 0, both of your if statements were false so your method didn't return any value (which means returned None).

Which means you tried to unpack None
`grid_x, grid_y, dx = None`

Answer (score 0):

Integer 0's boolean value is False

```
In [169]: bool(0)
Out[169]: False
```

Since you're x_min is 0, none of the if blocks in your code get executed and your function returns a None which cannot be unpacked.

If you want to check if an arguments has been passed or not, you should do

```
if arg is not None
```